# Health app double counts steps

Tags: ios, health.app

I am using an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.2. It happens that `Health` app doubles step count (and therefore also doubles distance). I know this beacause the amount is too high (about double, I should be running to have >6 km/hour walking speed) and I beacause I tested it (I know the walking distance to my work because of Google) I have checked on `Privacy` which apps can write walking distance and I switched them off, however everything remains the same.

In addition, I checked `Data sources` on the `Step` dashboard on `Health` following fbara's suggestion. However there are only two apps on `Data Sources`: my `Phone` and `Health` App. None of the can be unchecked nor removed nor dragged up and down. The data  supplied by them is very weird: `Health` App supplies little steps certain specifics days while my `Phone` source supplies everyday almost all steps. Its supply is already doubled.

It is worth noting that for a long time I didn't have problems

Thanks in advance!

Does some one know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `Health` app is still (even after you turned things off) aggregating step data.  Instead of going to `Privacy`, go to the `Health` app.  Next go to the dashboard and tap on the `Steps` pane. Tap `Share Data` and then the `Edit` button on the top right.  Make sure only 1 app is supplying the step data, whichever app you want to use.

While still in `Edit` mode, go to the `Data Sources` section.  Drag that single source to the top so it's the first row.

Hopefully, this will prevent any other source from supplying step data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer fbara. However there are only two apps on `Data Sources`: my Phone and `Health App`. None of the can be unchecked nor removed nor dragged up and down. The data  supplied by them is very weird: `Health App` supplies little steps certain specifics days while my `Phone` source supplies everyday almost all steps. Its supply is already doubled. It's worth saying that the health start doubling the count quite recently. In the beginning it was not like this